# GTK/Qt On PLT Scheme

Tags: linux, user-interface, racket

When you compile something written in PLT Scheme on Linux that have a GUI the final will be in a grey(default) theme of Linux, but I want to know

- If it's possible to integrate PLT Scheme with GTK or Qt?

  - How to do this?

**Example of grey(default) theme:**
[Grey Theme Frame http://i.imagehost.org/0219/gui.png](http://i.imagehost.org/0219/gui.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux version of PLT is based on an old fork from wxWindows (from before it was renamed to wxWidgets).  There is work going on to eventually replace all of the C and C++ code with Scheme code, and also move from a raw X backend to using gtk.  Until this is done (which might take a while), the best thing to do is to stick with the usual mred-based code; this way it will continue to work fine when the switch is done -- and you still keep the advantage of portability (since it behaves the same on Windows and on OS X too).

Comment: Here's [an update](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2010/12/racket-version-5.html) on the situation.